# ARM template cleanup

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Is there any tool or script which can list unused parameters and variables in an ARM template?

I am regularly getting task for ARM template cleanup.

I can manually write a C# code to do that but wondering if there is already any existing tool to cleanup in a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio code with ARM Template extensión shows unused parameters\variables.

Answer (score 3):

I've recently switched to VS Code for editing ARM templates, the tooling here is much more consistent. Edit in VS Code, run/test them in VS 2017. Install [Azure Resource Manager Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools) extension.